# Doxygen to document all functions in a class with call graph?

Tags: c++, doxygen, function-calls

What would be the best way to figure out all the calls made in a C++ class? I would like to not only find all the calls, I want to find out functions that aren't being called at all so I could clean up my code. I have heard that doxygen can work miracles when it generates the call graphs but it seems it is only generating call graphs for my constructor and like one other function when I have a bunch more I need.

All my class functions have been documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We really need more information here, for example, have you documented all your class methods? Have you made any changes to the default doxygen configuration file? As a first step try setting

```
CALL_GRAPH = YES
EXTRACT_ALL = YES 
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES = YES
```

in the [doxygen configuration file](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_collaboration_graph).